# How to dismiss keyboard after search in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

how to dismiss keyboard after search in mobile using react js ? i want to dismiss keyboard in mobile for responsive design after search. i use `onFocus` and `onBlur` but it didn't work at all.

my input

```
 <input
    type="text"
    name="url"
    ref={register}
    placeholder="Paste product link or Search from million of products..."
    defaultValue={q !== undefined ? q : ""}
    style={{ background: "none" }}
                        />
```

my submit function

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.reset();

        let regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%\-\/]))?/;

        // Again check it is link or keyword
        if (regex.test(data.url)) {
            router.push({
                pathname: '/product',
                query: { url: encodeURI(data.url) },
            })
        }
        else {
            setIsProductsLoading(true)
            router.push({
                pathname: '/products',
                query: { q: data.url, page: 1 },
            })
        }
    }
```

i also use

```
 if(e.key == 'Enter'){
        e.target.blur();
    }
```

this method to try dismiss keyboard but it also didn't work.

Comment: Is your Search button inside a `Form` ?

Comment: yes, ```<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}> </form>``` like this

Answer (score 1):

how about `e.target[0].blur();` before `e.preventDefault();`.

i use next.js, but it worked!

If you can't, let's `console.log('event:', e);` and is there input element in e.target?